# How to rename a directory in JTree?

Tags: java

I am making a file browser using JTree. I need to rename a directory (folder). So far I have succeeded in renaming the directory, but I can`t rename the node. This is what I have so far:

```
public TreePath findTreePath(File find) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < tree.getRowCount(); ii++) {
        TreePath treePath = tree.getPathForRow(ii);
        Object object = treePath.getLastPathComponent();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) object;
        File nodeFile = (File) node.getUserObject();

        if (nodeFile == find) {
            return treePath;
        }
    }
    // not found!
    return null;
}

private void renameFile() {
       if (currentFile==null) {
            showErrorMessage("No file selected to rename.","Select File");
            return;
        }

        String renameTo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "New Name");
        if (renameTo!=null) {
            try {
                boolean directory = currentFile.isDirectory();
                TreePath parentPath = findTreePath(currentFile.getParentFile());
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode =
                    (DefaultMutableTreeNode)parentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                boolean renamed = currentFile.renameTo(new File(
                    currentFile.getParentFile(), renameTo));
                if (renamed) {
                    if (directory) {
                        // rename the node..

                        // delete the current node..
                        TreePath currentPath = findTreePath(currentFile);
                        System.out.println(currentPath);
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode =
                            (DefaultMutableTreeNode)currentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                        treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);

                        treeModel.reload();
                        // add a new node..
                    }

                    showChildren(parentNode);
                } else {
                    String msg = "The file '" +
                        currentFile +
                        "' could not be renamed.";
                    showErrorMessage(msg,"Rename Failed");
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                showThrowable(t);
            }
        }
        gui.repaint();
}
```

currentFile is the folder I want to rename. Everything works except the visualization of the renamed folder. I would be grateful, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
    if (directory) {

                File oldFile = fmng.currentFile;
                File newFile = new File(oldFile.getParent(), renameTo);
                Files.move(oldFile.toPath(), newFile.toPath());

                //System.out.println("path" + newFile.getPath());

                TreePath currentPath = fmng.findTreePath(fmng.currentFile);
                //System.out.println(currentPath);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                fmng.treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);

                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(newFile);
                fmng.treeModel.insertNodeInto(newNode, parentNode, parentNode.getChildCount());

                //fmng.setFileDetails(newFile);
                renamed = true;
            } else {
                renamed = fmng.currentFile.renameTo(new File(fmng.currentFile.getParentFile(), renameTo));
            }
            if (renamed) {
                fmng.showChildren(parentNode);
            } else {
                String msg = "The file '" + fmng.currentFile + "' could not be renamed.";
                fmng.showErrorMessage(msg, "Rename Failed");
            }
```

I had to change the renaming method, then delete and add the node again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `updateUI` method after modifying the `JTree` to visualize the changes.

Ex: `tree.updateUI();`